# Gnuplot x-axis scaling

Tags: graph, gnuplot, scaling

Sorry about the poorly articulated title, I couldn't think of a title that would suffice without explaination.

I have a graph with an x axis with an irrelevant scale. What I want to do is have a second x-axis, which I know is possible, that is scaled strangely.

The second axis is not used in plotting anything, I just need the top values to align with the  axis that "matters." Let's say that my axis is devided into 10 different tics, going from 0 - 1000.

`0--100--200--300--400--500--600--700--800--900--1000`

I would like the second x-axis to do this(heres the tricky part):

`0---0----0----0----0----0----0----0---100--200--500`

What I was thinking was having the values actually be 0-1000 as well, but have the label be different (having "0" as a label for 0,100,...,700 and then "100" , "200" , "500" as labels for their respective values.

I know it's possible in histograms, but I'm not dealing with histograms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
set x2range [0:1000]
set x2tics("0" 0, "0" 100, "0" 200, "0" 300, "0" 400, "0" 500, "0" 600, "0" 700, "100" 800, "200" 900, "500" 1000)
```